# Is there a "best practice" for overriding a contributed module's controller?

Tags: webforms, page-controller

I'm still relatively new to Drupal 8 and recently I came across an occasion to override the WebFormSubmissionListBuilder Controller.

I eventually found another project which had exactly the same need and they did it as below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_alter().
 *
 * @todo This alters all webform_submission entites but should alter only the ones in configured workflows.
 */
function academic_applications_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  /* @var $entity_types \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface[] */
  $entity_types['webform_submission']->setListBuilderClass('Drupal\academic_applications\WebFormSubmissionListBuilderOverride');
}
```

While this works I can see it being a real problem if more than one module tried to override another module's controller this way. However, I couldn't find a better way so I ended up using their method for now.

Is there a known or "best practices" for doing this? I don't see any obvious plugin points in the WebFormSubmissionListBuilder controller's code so taking it over seems to be the only way to extend it as far as I can tell.

Comment: Generally overriding a controller should be done by a custom module and not a contrib module. For example, for one of my larger enterprise clients, we override list builders to make customizations.  Your question makes the argument that the WebFormSubmissionListBuilder might need to be alterable.

Comment: Good point, alterable would be nice. In their case it was a contrib overriding a contrib. In my case it was a custom overriding the webform contrib. Both them and I had the same need in that we added another item to the dropdown action (options) buttons that's to the right of each item in the list and then implemented the code for the custom action we created.

Comment: Controllers unfortunately don't have an alter hook like forms do, but you could subscribe to KernelEvents::VIEW to get the controller result and set a modified build array, see [GetResponseForControllerResultEvent::setControllerResult](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-kernel%21Event%21GetResponseForControllerResultEvent.php/function/GetResponseForControllerResultEvent%3A%3AsetControllerResult/8.7.x)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To avoid conflicts with other modules you could alter the controller content in a [kernel VIEW event](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-kernel%21KernelEvents.php/constant/KernelEvents%3A%3AVIEW) similar to a form alter hook:

*src/EventSubscriber/ControllerAlterSubscriber.php:*
<?php

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

/**
 * Class ControllerAlterSubscriber.
 */
class ControllerAlterSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Alters the controller output.
   */
  public function onView(ViewEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $route = $request->attributes->get('_route');

    if ($route == 'entity.webform_submission.collection') {
      $build = $event->getControllerResult();
      if (is_array($build)) {
        // alter controller build array
        $build['added_content'] = ['#markup' => '<p>Added by ControllerAlterSubscriber.</p>'];

        $event->setControllerResult($build);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    // priority > 0 so that it runs before the controller output
    // is rendered by \Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber
    $events[KernelEvents::VIEW][] = ['onView', 50];
    return $events;
  }

}
```

*mymodule.services.yml:*

```
services:
  mymodule.controller_alter:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\ControllerAlterSubscriber
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Comment: This seems like a good workable solution.