# How can I style the webform submissions table?

Tags: theming, webforms

Using Drupal 9 and Webform, I'm unable to find the twig template used to output /contact/form/submissions.  Is there a place in the documentation that lists the twig templates?  I see there is a View created that looks like it has submissions, but disabling it doesn't break the page.  If there is a better way to style it, that could also work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "best practice" for overriding a contributed module's controller in Drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281093/is-there-a-best-practice-for-overriding-a-contributed-modules-controller-in-d)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Is there a "best practice" for overriding a contributed module's controller in Drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281093/is-there-a-best-practice-for-overriding-a-contributed-modules-controller-in-d)

If you override the WebformSubmissionListBuilder, you can do almost anything you want to the results, including custom theming.