# Alter a controller's render array via KernelEvents::VIEW

Tags: page-controller, event-subscribers

I'm trying to alter a contrib module controller's output via `KernelEvents::VIEW`. I want to display the output from the controller and append the markup returned from the event handler.
This is the code I am using, but it doesn't work as expected.

```php
class BuildAlter implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function alterBuild(ViewEvent $event) {
    $build = $event->getControllerResult();
    $build['content'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<p>Added by ControllerAlterSubscriber.</p>'
    ];

    $event->setControllerResult($build);
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      // The VIEW event occurs when the return value of a controller
      // is not a Response instance.
      KernelEvents::VIEW => ['alterBuild', 50],
    ];
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to register the service in *.services.yml. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281093/is-there-a-best-practice-for-overriding-a-contributed-modules-controller-in-d/281158#281158

Comment: The problem, the $build['content'] is not referenced in the main twig I wan to alter,
see below how content is output in twig.
`{{ last_checked }}`

{% for project_type in project_types %}
  <h3>{{ project_type.label }}</h3>
  {{ project_type.table }}
{% else %}
  <p>{{ no_updates_message }}</p>
{% endfor %}
`
Should I open an issue to output $build['content'] for that twig file, so other event listeners can alter/add the output via the 'content' key? I'm lost.

Comment: _Should I open an issue_ I don't think that would be appropriate, there's nothing in convention or best practice to say a `'content'` variable has to be used for a Twig template. Perhaps you could think about altering the route instead and building your own view based on the original plus your changes?

Comment: The markup in `content` is its own render item. A variable would be `#content` if placed with a template `#theme`.

Comment: Thank you @Clive, will use this approach

Comment: The [`ViewEvent`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-kernel%21Event%21ViewEvent.php/class/ViewEvent/9.2.x) class is only available on Drupal 9. On Drupal 8, the class to use is [`GetResponseForControllerResultEvent`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-kernel%21Event%21GetResponseForControllerResultEvent.php/class/GetResponseForControllerResultEvent/9.2.x). Drupal core code doesn't help much in understanding how to implement that event handler. None of the event handlers implemented by Drupal core uses `setControllerResult()`.

Comment: Looking at the Drupal core code used for that type of event handler, I can only understand the event handler should not assume the value returned from `$event->getControllerResult()` is an array. `RenderArrayNonHtmlSubscriber::onRespond()` and `MainContentViewSubscriber::onViewRenderArray()` check the value returned is an array, and assume it's a render array. `PsrResponseSubscriber::onKernelView()` checks the value returned implements `ResponseInterface`.