# How to modify a rendered HTML string by adding custom code to setContent() in core in a module?

Tags: 9

I want to override the HTML string returned by core using a custom module that replaces `$content['#markup']`, or the entire `$content` array returned by [`HtmlResponse::setContent()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21HtmlResponse.php/function/HtmlResponse%3A%3AsetContent/9.2.x).

I can override `Response::setContent()` by calling
`HtmlResponse::setContent()`. Exactly how do I add this to a custom module, for example implementing a service?

My goal is altering all the `<a>` tags to add a `<span>` tag to the ones that links to downloadable files.

Comment: You should tell us what your overall goal is, not just how you are trying to accomplish it.  This post needs more details.

Comment: @Jaypan - I want to run a REGEX on the rendered HTML string that will modify all the <a> tags by adding a <span> to the ones that link to downloadable files. I have the regex, Too many links from too many different sources to do this effectively in the theme so I want to try this approach

Comment: do you want to change a Form or Controller output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the output of a form see [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.8.x)

If you want to change the output of controllers see this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281093/is-there-a-best-practice-for-overriding-a-contributed-modules-controller-in-d). You can also subscribe to other [Kernel Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html) with that method and should be able to alter any output your site creates. (kernel.response is probably what you need)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to act on the rendered HTML of a render array rather than the structured content array before rendering, use a #post_render callback. See [How to alter page content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293517/how-to-alter-page-content)